# can not resize a table Column in a horizontally Scrollable div

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, resize, scrollable

I have a big table with 20 headers. I Want to resize the table columns but as the table is too big it stopped resizing. I have tried putting the table inside a `div` with `overflow:auto` but it will not scroll horizontally or make the `div` bigger when i try to resize the table columns.
i have added a sample of what i am trying to do below.
P.S. I am trying to do it without adding `jquery`.

```
<html>
<head>       
</head>
<style>

.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;  width:100%;}
.tg td{padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;}
.tg th{padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;}

.tg .tg-dvpl{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-0pky{
  top: 0;  
  z-index: 10;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: 70px;
  position: relative;
}
.tg tr{ position: relative;}


</style>
<body>



        <div style="height: 300px; overflow: auto;">
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-dvpl" colspan="5">H1</th>
    <th class="tg-dvpl" colspan="8">H2</th>
    <th class="tg-dvpl" colspan="8">H3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">#</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">4</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">5</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">6</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">7</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">9</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">11</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">12</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">13</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">14 </td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">15</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">16</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">17</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">18</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">19</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
            <td></td>
    <td  colspan="3"></td>
            <td></td>
    <td  colspan="4"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
    <td  colspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
  </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>       
            <td></td>
           <td></td>
          </tr>
    </table>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You required width to table then need overflow to parent class. check snippet.

```css
div {
  width: 1000px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 1900px;
}

.tg td {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.tg th {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.tg .tg-dvpl {
  border-color: inherit;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-0pky {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: 70px;
  position: relative;
}

.tg tr {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="tg">
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-dvpl" colspan="5">H1</th>
      <th class="tg-dvpl" colspan="8">H2</th>
      <th class="tg-dvpl" colspan="8">H3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">4</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">5</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">6</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">7</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">8</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">9</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">10</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">11</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">12</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">13</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">14 </td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">15</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">16</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">17</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">18</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">19</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="4"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: But if i put a long data inside <td></td> it stops working.
it will not resize also it won't scroll.

Comment: i added the long data in one td and its working. check updated answer.

Comment: sorry for not making my problem clear. As you see it changes vertically not horizontally. the td with long text only shrinks, i wanted it to expand to the right.
is it possible to do with CSS only?

Comment: Its quit hard to understand what you want.